# No rows returned using count in having clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2005 I have a table where I have distinct file names associated with certain personal ID numbers. I want to pull up all of file names where the count of the personal ID's is greater than 1. This is what I'm doing but it's pulling up 0 records:

```
SELECT [file_name], per_ID
FROM mytable
GROUP BY [file_name], per_ID
HAVING COUNT(per_ID) > 1
ORDER BY per_ID, [file_name] ASC
```

I've also tried the following with the same results:

```
SELECT [file_name], per_ID, COUNT(per_ID)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY [file_name],per_ID
HAVING COUNT(per_ID) > 1
ORDER BY per_ID, [file_name] ASC
```

If anyone can show me what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it.

Here's the table structure and data example:

```
file_name | per_ID
9995573157  1111
5996110978  2222
5996111208  3333
8996693000  3333
8996693215  4444
7997617867  5555
9997335346  5555
```

The results I'm looking for would be the file names from per_ID 3333 and 5555

```
5996111208  
8996693000
7997617867  
9997335346
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so we just need to do this in 2 steps. First, get a list of per_ids that appear more than once and then get a list of file_names that correspond to those per_ids.

```
select file_name
from mytable
where per_id in (
    select per_id from mytable group by per_id having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks Derek. For some reason this is still returning 0 rows. I've updated my question so hopefully what I'm looking for is more clear.

Comment: I've edited my query - i misunderstood what you were trying to do. I think this solves it now, though.

Comment: That did it. Thanks Derek. I've been wracking my brain over this.

Answer (score 0):

Personal ID sounds like a key and grouping by it will always return distinct groups. Why don't you try grouping by the file name alone? Rest of the query remains the same.